# Display live processed webcam stream using matlab

Tags: matlab, real-time, webcam

I am trying to employ a chroma key algorithm on a live video. I need to take a live webcam input, process it in real time and display it. I already have the chroma key algorithm working on images.

How do I process the webcam input and display it immediately. I have tried using snapshot() and passing the image to the chroma key algorithm but it is too slow even if I increase the rate of snapshots. I want a smooth output.

[ Also, if there is a better alternative than Matlab please let me know. ]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getsnapshot()` which connects to the camera and disconnects on EVERY single frame (thus slow framerates), try to use videoinput and then `preview` the connection: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/imaq/preview.html

This example is made for you:
http://www.mathworks.de/products/imaq/code-examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/imaq/demoimaq_LiveHistogram.html

As shown you can even define a callback-handler-function which is called on every newly received frame.

Answer (score 0):

You must set `TriggerType` to `manual`, or else `getsnapshot()` will create (and destroy) a conection to the camera everytime you need a frame. By setting it to manual, you can start the camera once, get the frames and stop the camera when you're done.

Here is an example:

```
vidobj = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'RGB24_640x480');
triggerconfig(vidobj, 'manual');

start(vidobj);
while true % Or any stop condition
    img = getsnapshot(vidobj);

    % Process the frame.
    ...

    imshow(img);
    drawnow;
end
```